# Python gets Killed (probably memory leak)

Tags: python

I have been working on this for a few weeks now and I've read many questions about python memory leak but I just can't figure it out.

I have a file that contains about 7 million lines. For each line, I need to create a dictionary. So this is a list of dictionary that looks like:

```
[{'a': 2, 'b':1}{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1}]
```

What I am doing is...

```
list = []
for line in file.readlines():
    terms = line.split(" ")
    dict = {}
    for term in terms:
        if term in dict:
            dict[term] = dict[term] + 1
        else:
            dict[term] = 1
    list.append(dict.copy())
    dict.clear()
file.close()
```

The problem is that when I run this it always gets killed around the 6000000th line. Originally I was just doing `dict = {}` but changed it so I do dict.clear() after reading similar posts, but it didn't improve anything. I know some posts mentioned about circular references and I looked into my code but I didn't think I have that problem.

I doubt that storing 7 million dictionaries in a list can't be handled in Python? I would appreciate any advice on how I can run the whole things without getting killed.

(The version is 2.7.4)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco I edited my question a bit, but what I'm trying to do is  to store the term count dictionary for each line

Comment: Did you try replacing _for line in file.readlines():_ by _for line in file:_ ?

Comment: Are you working in an environment that may impose some other process limits (CPU time?) I'd suggest trying to iterate through the file doing *nothing* (i.e., `pass`) to see if it's a problem by itself.

Comment: Ummm, that must be reported to [Greenpeace](http://greenpeace.org)

Comment: @NicholasRiley I tried iterating through the file doing nothing and it runs without a problem. I guess this shows that I just can't store them.. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: How big is the python image getting? And what platform are you using?

Comment: @Marcin I'm using Mac but I'm sshing to a shared server. Sorry I don't know a lot about python but how do I get the image??

Comment: @kabichan Are you sshing to linux? If so use `top` or `ps` to see memory usage. The point is that both linux and windows have a maximum image size. It's possible that you're suffering this problem not because of a leak, but simply because your task requires too much memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('input') as fin:
    term_counts = [Counter(line.split()) for line in fin]
```

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve with your code.

This avoids the `.readlines()` loading the file into memory first, utilises `Counter` to do the counting and builds the list in one go without faffing around blanking/assign/clearing dictionaries/appending to lists...

Comment: I tried and it still got killed.. only thing I did differently from yours is that I have a variable for the filename, so I did `with open(filename) as fin:` and the rest is the same.

Comment: @kabichan That's as simple as it gets for what you want - sounds like you might have to store the data on disk/in a DB

Comment: If this is not because I'm not doing what I can do, then I can move on and try something else. I'll accept yours as the answer because it looks like this would solve similar problems. Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: @kabichan yup - if it still dies - then you can't store a list a list of dicts as you want for your data on your system. Look at a maybe a simple keystore database with line number as key, and store the counts in that... Or possibly even some form of FTI using sqlite3 etc... There will be ways to achieve what you want but not this way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you could have a memory leak with a snippet of code as simple as that, because python uses at least half-way decent garbage collection.  One potential issue is that you might be running out of memory (so definitely avoid .readlines for starters; use "for line in my_file" instead); also a dictionary actually uses quite a bit of memory for various reasons -- one is that a dictionary intentionally uses a hash table considerably larger than your actual current set of keys, both to help mitigate collisions but also to be able to quickly add a lot of new keys if needed, with amortized O(1) time per insertion.  Since you are getting so close to the end of your file before it dies, one thing you could try is storing your final dict as a 2-tuple of k-tuples, where the first k-tuple contains the k keys you want to store, and the second k-tuple is your k counts for the k keys.  This should save some memory, at the expense that in order to do a look-up of my_key in one of your 2-tuples T you'll need to do something like:

```
match_idx = [i for i in xrange(len(T[0])) if T[0][i] == my_key]
if len(match_idx) == 0:
  # no match, do whatever
else: #match
  count = T[1][match_idx[0]] 
  # now do whatever with count
```

The running time for a look up will be linear in the number of keys you have to search through, instead of constant time (although note that hashing to do a dictionary look-up is not a trivial operation, so the constant is bigger than a typical constant for a simpler operation).  If you stored your keys in sorted order then you could use binary search to quickly find your key but this would require more code, and i'm assuming you're using python in part because it tends to give short code.  However if you are already successfully creating 6 million of your dictionaries, then on average your 7 million dictionaries must not have many keys in them.  So if you really want to use python for your data set, this may be one of the only ways to go unless you get a machine with more memory.